# wp_insert_post() does not support variable

Tags: terms

I have a problem with the following function as I will pass a variable in [`wp_insert_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term): `wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() );`

It does not work if I do this: `wp_insert_term( 'abc', $taxonomy, $args );`

The code is as following:

```
function insert_city($term) {
    echo $term;
    if (!term_exists($term, "property-city")) {
        $args = array('description'=> 'There is Described Glasgow.','slug' => 'glasgow',);
        wp_insert_term('hellotesting','property-city',$args);
        // $i = get_cat_id($title);
        //  return $i;
```

Comment: You're confident that `$var` has the correct value when you call it?

Comment: yes $var have exect value as i passed.........

Comment: yes i am confident............

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in PHP between a string and a variable set to a string, so the problem is elsewhere.

Most likely it is with passing the `slug` argument as mentioned in the codex for `wp_insert_term`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term :

> If 'slug' argument exists then the slug will be checked to see if it is
>   not a valid term. If that check succeeds (it is not a valid term),
>   then it is added and the term id is given. If it fails, then a check
>   is made to whether the taxonomy is hierarchical and the parent
>   argument is not empty. If the second check succeeds, the term will be
>   inserted and the term id will be given. If the slug argument is empty,
>   then it will be calculated from the term name.

You could try understanding that -  or just try removing the slug argument and allowing it to be generated automatically from the string passed.